# How to Import email list on Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have just register amazon ses email services and verified domain as well as sender email address.
Now I cant find where I can import list of email ids. These are my subscriber email ids where I want to send mails.

Can anyone let me know how to import list? I cant find any option on dashboard.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon Simple Email Service (SES) is an outbound-only email sending service. It takes the place of an SMTP server and provides extra capabilities that improve deliverability of your email.

You pass an email and recipient list to SES via an API call or by treating it as your SMTP server. SES then sends the email to the recipients. It does not alter the contents of the email, so it cannot insert fields such as "Dear ,".

SES is not a list manager. It does not maintain a "list" of subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SES is a SMTP server not a mail client to send mail. Either you need to upload your mail list on the db to send it of you have to use any mail client like sendy,mailchimp and all to do it.